# Cannot export a table to CSV together with header with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a table inside a worksheet. I used the following found here

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2017/09/save-excel-range-data-as-csv-file-through-excel-vba/#VBA-to-save-excel-table-to-csv

```
Sub saveTableToCSV()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim csvFilePath As String
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim tblArr
Dim rowArr
Dim csvVal

Set tbl = Worksheets("EXPORT").ListObjects("TableName")
csvFilePath = "C:\CSVFile.csv"
tblArr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value

fNum = FreeFile()
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum
For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
    rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
    csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ",")
    Print #1, csvVal
Next
Close #fNum
Set tblArr = Nothing
Set rowArr = Nothing
Set csvVal = Nothing
End Sub
```

How to include the table header in the csv? My thought is to do the following

```
tblArr2 = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Value
```

But how I will join the tables?

Additionally, how to include UTF-8 support to the saved CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're selecting the range of cells, you are just selecting the table data:

```
tblArr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
```

What you need to do is to select the entire table range, like this:

```
tblArr = tbl.Range.Value
```

You can take a look at [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) article for some more reference

Answer (score 0):

I added the following

```
rowArr2 = Application.Index(tblArrHeaders, 0, 0)
csvVal2 = VBA.Join(rowArr2, ",")
Print #1, csvVal2 + csvVal
```

so I got

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("table")
csvFilePath = "C:\CSVFile.csv"
tblArr = tbl.DataBodyRange.Value
tblArrHeaders = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Value

fNum = FreeFile()
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum

rowArr2 = Application.Index(tblArrHeaders, 0, 0)
csvVal2 = VBA.Join(rowArr2, ",")
Print #1, csvVal2 + csvVal

For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
    rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
    csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ",")
    Print #1, csvVal
Next
Close #fNum
Set tblArr = Nothing
Set rowArr = Nothing
Set csvVal = Nothing
```